# SQL - Finding all rows with a different values in a column for the same value in another column when combining two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two MS Access tables `Table 1` and `Table 2` where I am interested in values in `Col1`, `Col2` and `Col3`, where `Col2` could be empty. Using SQL, I want to be able to combine both tables, eliminate duplicates and find all rows for which non-empty `Col2` values are different for the same value in `Col3`.

A example for the combined two tables without empty values in `Col2`

```
+-----------+---------+---------+
|    Col1   |  Col2   |  Col3   |
+-----------+---------+---------+
| James     | bar     | 3       |
| Bob       | red     | 2       |
| Jess      | red     | 3       |
| Don       | foo     | 1       |
| James     | bar     | 1       |
| Mike      | red     | 3       |
| Paula     | foo     | 4       |
| Paula     | red     | 2       |
| Tom       | red     | 2       |
+-----------+---------+---------+
```

Would give:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+
| James     | bar     | 3       |
| Jess      | red     | 3       |
| Mike      | red     | 3       |
| Don       | foo     | 1       |
| James     | bar     | 1       |
+-----------+---------+---------+
```

To combine the tables and eliminate duplicates where `Col2` is not empty, I can use:

```
SELECT [Col1], [Col2], [Col3]
FROM [Table 1]
WHERE [Col2] <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT [Col1], [Col2], [Col3]
FROM [Table 2]
WHERE [Col2] <> ''
GROUP BY [Col1], [Col2], [Col3]
```

Using the result from the above statement, I would like to know which `SELECT` statement should be used to accomplish what I want.

Comment: Showing us example data for table 1 and table 2 and then expected results woud be easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `exists`:

```
select distinct t.*
from table1 as t
where t.col2 is not null and
      exists (select 1
              from table1 as t2
              where t2.col3 = t.col3 and t2.col2 <> t.col2
             );
```